# Laravel combining has() and whereHas()

Tags: php, laravel, audio, laravel-5, has-many

I'm trying to combine some methods in Eloquent but can't seem to get it together properly. I have a query that pulls all items where the hasMany count is 0.

So basically I want to know where the relationship is "empty". In this case I have an item with audio samples. So, I want to get items where there are no audio samples yet.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item')->has('audios', '=', 0);
```

This works completely fine. However I also want to add a filter based on male and female audio samples. If I use `whereHas` I can get the filter but only directly and can't get the `has 0` clause on it.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item')->whereHas('audios', function ($q) {
    $q->where('gender', 'female');
});
```

But no I want combine them and can't figure this bit out. So "get all items with no female audio samples".

Not a lot of documentation on these except in the trivial case, I tried a few variations but it's not coming up right. Just completely empty sets or only female or male directly without that "empty" 0 set.

Here is the query I would like to get:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `audios`
    WHERE `audios`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
    AND `audios`.`gender`='female'
) = 0
```

Comment: Not sure if you meant to get females AND empties or empty females`$q->where('gender', 'female')->orWhere('audios', '=', 0);` or `$q->where('gender', 'female')->where('audios', '=', 0);`

Comment: @Peh `audios` is the relationship name. so an `item->hasMany('audios')`. I need all items where "doesn't have any female audios". I updated the post to include the direct query I"m looking for.

Comment: couldn't test it but can you try this? `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item')->has('audios', '=', 0)->where('gender', 'female');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereHas`, `doesntHave` etc are all methods that, in the end, call `has`. If you look at the signature of `whereHas` you can see that it allows a count to be passed as well:

```
public function whereHas($relation, Closure $callback, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)
```

So you could do that, or just use `whereDoesntHave`:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item')->whereDoesntHave('audios', function ($q) {
    $q->where('gender', 'female');
});
```